# If this options is selected show div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a div to show if a certain option is selected as well as a previous option in another select tag is selected.

This jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LehL1pru/ works but what I want to do is to make sure that the previous select option equals a certain value.

```
$(function() {
    $("#smallplantable").click(function() {
    if (this.value == ""){
        $('.plantableone').hide();
    }
        if (this.value == "plantablenone") {
        $('.plantableone').hide();
        }
        if (this.value == "plantableone") {
        $('.plantableone').show();
        }
    });
});
```

What I have tried is adding && to the if statement in jquery but it doesn't seem to be working as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/5bLc1f9b/1/

```
$(function() {
    $("#smallplantable").click(function() {
    if (this.value == ""){
        $('.plantableone').hide();
    }
        if (this.value == "plantablenone") {
        $('.plantableone').hide();
        }
        if (this.value == "plantableone" && "#numberofstaff".value == "smalljobsite") {
        $('.plantableone').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Anyone have an idea why this isn't working or have an alternative option?

Thanks.

Comment: "#numberofstaff".value is just a string. Perhaps you intended $("#numberofstaff").val()

Comment: Your selector for `"#numberofstaff".value` is incorrect. That's essentially all that's wrong here.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/5bLc1f9b/7/ I know there are answers but this is my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle. Though the code needs to be more tidy. But for reference, you can rely on it

Also, you are using jQuery, however, you did not included jQuery in your fiddle. And if you are using jQuery then in your code, use jQuery functions only - not must though but quite handy

http://jsfiddle.net/5bLc1f9b/3/

```
$(function() {
    $("#smallplantable").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == ""){
        $('.plantableone').hide();
    }
        if ($(this).val() == "plantablenone") {
        $('.plantableone').hide();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "plantableone" && $("#numberofstaff").val() == "smalljobsite") {

        $('.plantableone').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for and thanks for the proper way. However I want the div that shows "price here" to hide if they select another number of staff other than smalljobsite if that makes sense

Comment: It completely makes sense to me. I have updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5bLc1f9b/9/

Comment: I have added one more version. I hop you like it - http://jsfiddle.net/5bLc1f9b/11/

Comment: In the newer version - the toggle will occur for change in both the select.

Comment: The last one is exactly what I was looking for! It all makes sense once you see it but it was just not coming to me on how to do it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#smallplantable").click(function() {
        var firstSelect = $('#numberofstaff').val();
    if (this.value == ""){
        $('.plantableone').hide();
    }
        if (this.value == "plantablenone") {
        $('.plantableone').hide();
        }
        if (this.value == "plantableone" && firstSelect == "smalljobsite") {
        $('.plantableone').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Your selector is wrong for `"#numberofstaff"`, which is why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the jquery object for the first select, change as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("#smallplantable").click(function() {
    if (this.value == ""){
        $('.plantableone').hide();
    }
        if (this.value == "plantablenone") {
        $('.plantableone').hide();
        }
        if (this.value == "plantableone" && $("#numberofstaff").val() == "smalljobsite") {
        $('.plantableone').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Note that i've changed `"#numberofstaff".value` for `$("#numberofstaff").val()`